Axiomatization of the theory of finite structures in a signature consisting only of function symbols
The following question is inspired by this question here. In that question, the OP asked whether there is a theory $T$ in the signature of a single binary operation $\{\ast\}$, s.t. $T$ admits both finite and infinite models, and furthermore $T$ is the same as the theory of its finite models. I noted in the comments that one may simply choose $T$ to be the theory of all finite $\{\ast\}$-structures. However, it is not immediately clear to me whether $T$ is recursively axiomatizable. I conjectured that $T$ can be axiomatized by an axiom schema as follows: for any $n$-tuple of terms $(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ in $n + m$ variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m$, for any given $y_1, \cdots, y_m$, the function $(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \mapsto (t_1(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m), \cdots, t_n(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m))$ is injective iff it is surjective. Symbolically, for any terms $t_1, \cdots, t_n$ with variables in $x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m$,
$$\forall y_1 \cdots \forall y_m \; [(\forall x_1 \cdots \forall x_n \forall x_1' \cdots \forall x_n' \; [(\bigvee_{i = 1}^n x_i \neq x_i') \Rightarrow (\bigvee_{i = 1}^n t_i(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m) \neq t_i(x_1', \cdots, x_n', y_1, \cdots, y_m))]) \Leftrightarrow (\forall z_1 \cdots \forall z_n \exists x_1 \cdots \exists x_n \; [\bigwedge_{i = 1}^n t_i(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m) = z_i])]$$
Questions:

Is the above axiomatization correct? More generally, suppose the signature $L$ consists only of function symbols (including constant symbols), does the above axiom schema (with terms now using the function symbols in $L$) axiomatize the theory $T$ of finite $L$-structures?
@NoahSchweber proposed, in the comments of the linked question, that one might need to consider definable functions instead of just terms. More precisely, we should consider an axiom schema over all formulae $\varphi$ saying that whenever $\varphi$ defines a function $(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m) \mapsto (z_1, \cdots, z_n)$, then it satisfies the same injective iff surjective property. So if the axiom schema in $1$ is not sufficient, is this expanded version of axiom schema sufficient to axiomatize $T$?
If the above is not true in general, are there some conditions on the signature $L$ that ensure the above axiom schema (either the term version or the definable function version) axiomatizes $T$?
Again, if neither $1$ nor $2$ is true, then is $T$ recursively axiomatizable at all? (Excluding trivial cases, such as when $L$ consists only of constant symbols.)


Since every finite structure is interpretable in a finite $\{*\}$-structure (basically: a binary relation symbol, let alone a binary function symbol, is already "expressively complete"), the theory of the finite $\{*\}$-structures is as complicated as the theory of finite structures of whatever (finite) language you like. And by Trakhtenbrot's theorem, this is co-c.e. complete and so in particular not computably axiomatizable.

Here's a sketch of the claim in the first half of my first sentence. For concreteness, I'll just prove how to "re-implement" a structure $\mathcal{A}$ in a language with one 5-ary relation symbols $R$ as a $\{*\}$-structure $\mathcal{A}'$, which is finite if $\mathcal{A}$ is.
The underlying set of $\mathcal{A}'$ will be the disjoint union of:

The set of tuples $A^{\le 5}$.

A "check" element $\#$.

Booleans $\top$ and $\perp$.

A "whoops" element $0$.


The operation $*$ will be interpreted as follows:

If $\sigma,\tau\in A^{\le 5}$ and $\vert\sigma\vert+\vert\tau\vert\le 5$ then $\sigma*\tau=\sigma\tau$.

If $\sigma\in A^{5}$, then $\sigma*\#=\top$ if $R(\sigma)$ holds in $\mathcal{A}$, and $\perp$ otherwise.

$\top*\top=\perp*\perp=\top$ (this lets us distinguish between $\top$ and $\perp$).

All other applications of $*$ yield $0$.



I suppose this at least requires some conditions on the signature. If there are only unary function symbols and constant symbols, this wouldn't work?

@DavidGao You mean if we replace ${*}$ with a signature consisting only of $\le 1$-ary functions? Yes, such a signature would no longer be "universal."

I see. I was surprised, but in retrospect this does make a lot of sense. Thank you! Are you aware if, when ${\ast}$ is replaced by a signature consisting only of unary function symbols and constant symbols (perhaps also unary relation symbols), whether the axiom schema I proposed (and extended to definable functions, per your suggestion) would provide an effective axiomatization? Or is that still false?

@DavidGao Unary functions can encode constants and unary relations via a similar strategy to that in my answer, so you may as well just have unary function symbols. I suspect that for this restricted setting the answer is yes, but I'm not sure.

I see. Thank you!
